# Share data between processes one in c# and the other in Javascript (on Windows)

Tags: javascript, c#, shared-memory

What would be the easiest way to share data between two processes one in c# and the other in Javascript (separated application). Another issue is that for Javascript I cannot add additional libraries.

Comment: Building a Web API is a very flexible way to share data with all kind of applications

Comment: An easy way is grpc https://grpc.io/

Comment: JS apps often use WebSockets to connect to other applications - that's a third choice for you

Comment: What kind of communication do you need? Simple message passing? Or more sophisticated orchestration?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov Simple data passing

Comment: Simple tcp socket sounds like a good solution then.